# List<String> with a Value 'Integer'

Tags: java, string, list, integer

Are there any alternatives to? (1 group )

```
    class team {
        List<String> team = new ArrayList<String>
        int score = 0;
    }
```

Is there an object that that store a List or Set 'String', that can hold a value of a Integer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. but you can convert that integer to `String`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to make a List or Set that can accept both Strings and integers? In that case, if you use generics then you have to declare them as holding the `Object` class since that's the only common superclass between `Integer` and `String`.

Comment: Maybe a `List<>` isn't the data structure you're looking for?  What actual values is this structure going to hold?  Perhaps you're trying to use a `List` where a custom object is more appropriate?

Comment: @Kon Think about a group that has a certain score. Instead of storing them apart, i want the group and the score as one variable.

Comment: @user2803086 If your groups are unique, you could use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` . Then you'd be add key-value pairs to the Map like "Group1", 6.

Comment: @user2803086: In that case it really sounds like you want a custom object.  If a Score is something which describes a Group, then a Group object should have a Score property on it.  It may also have a `List<T>` of something else, and other properties.  Consider one of Martin Fowler's refactoring patterns, Replace Array With Object: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-array-with-object

Comment: The group/team contains two or more strings. Each group/team has a score (integer value)

Comment: @user2803086: Then you want a `Group` or `Team` object.  It contains a collection of strings (`List` is a nice default, but you may want to consider something like a `HashSet` if you want to enforce uniqueness for example) and an integer.  Then instead of working with an untyped collection which could contain anything (causing your code to require lots of runtime checking which gets in the way of the actual program logic), you'd have a typed object which can internally enforce its own data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a new type that holds both the `String` and the `int` that you care about, e.g.:

```
public class Score {
    String group;
    int score;
}

...

List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
```

---

To answer your original question, though: The narrowest common type between `String` and `Integer` is `Object`, and you can construct such a `List`:

```
List<Object> group = new ArrayList<Object>();
group.add("string");
group.add(1);
```

Of course, this isn't restrictive to just `String` and `Integer` types, you can add any type of object.

Alternatively, you could coerce your `Integer` into a `String`:

```
String someNumber = String.valueOf(1);
```

Or construct a new class that is more restrictive, and acts as a kind of union:

```
public class StringOrInteger {
    private final Object value;
    public StringOrInteger(String string) {
        value = string;
    }
    public StringOrInteger(Integer integer) {
        value = integer;
    }
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

...and then have a list of these:

```
List<StringOrInteger> group = new ArrayList<StringOrInteger>();
```

(which will be at least compile-time restrictive)

You could get fancier with the class, and make it so that it returns a correctly cast object, but I suppose it depends on your use-case where you want to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a Score object:

```
class Score
{
  int points;
  String groupName;
}
```

and then a `List<Score>` of them